# Schools for Game Theory/Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, game-theory, advice

I am looking into both Game Theory and Algebraic Geometry for graduate study and potentially doing a thesis in. I wanted to know if there are areas of mathematics that rely on both algebraic geometry and game theory. Also, which schools are relatively strong in both fields?

Comment: It would seem really crucial to figure out if this is something that exists before getting invested in the idea. You might try the Economics beta SE, asking more broadly for any applications of algebraic geometry to economics. I've really never heard of such a thing.

Comment: You might want to take the last question out because it is explicitly mentioned as off-topic in the help center. The first question is not a mathematical problem either but the jury is still out.

Comment: Here is one professor who works on both fields [Real Algebraic Geometry  in Computational Game Theory](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/2185/slidesmiltersen.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are applications of specialized parts of AG to specialized parts of game theory -- see e.g. [this dissertation](https://people.mbi.ohio-state.edu/datta.53/thesis.pdf) by Datta -- but neither of these are going to be the focus of your average AG or game theory program.  If you really specifically want to do something on this you should probably try programs that specialize in computational and/or real algebraic geometry and then talk to a professor in advance.

Comment: Seems like Berkeley is a good option since this dissertation was from a Berkeley student.

Comment: I wouldn't go from this to assuming that Berkeley is a robust center for what you want to do. Sturmfels is really pretty singular, it seems to me.

Comment: But probably a place with an economics (or possibly finance) department that is strong in theory and also has a good  math department would work.

Comment: No, I don't think so.  There are plenty of places with a strong math department that don't have any algebraic geometers at all.